# To move between windows in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I have the following in .screenrc

```
 # I want to use Vim's navigation keys
 bind h focus down
 bind t focus up
```

I would like to be able to move by `Ctrl-A t` to a next window, while by `Ctrl-A h to the previous window.

However, the above mappings do not work anymore for me.

**How can you move between windows in Screen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind h prev
bind t next
```

Comment: @ Do you know which is the binding if I want to move vertically between split windows? --- Neither of the commands move between Splits which I want to.

Comment: I hadn't realized you were talking about split windows.  The bindings you specified in your original question works fine for me here.

Comment: @Sean: I get `E73: tag stack empty` after trying to move up to the second split. The commands worked for me initially too. However, the problem started to occur after structuring my .screenrc by sourcing.

Comment: My .screenrc has `meta` as `C-A t`. I put unsuccessfully to my .screenrc `bind t`, but the binding persists.

Comment: Can you just post your entire .screenrc file?

Comment: @Sean: My .screenrc is at http://github.com/masi/Sam/blob/17b0750c5c3a98a44392afd095a1140fd3f7ba17/.screenrc, while its sources at http://github.com/masi/bin/tree/34a19262f85aeeb2fbd334d68f051f2a8966aa49/screen

Comment: In mappings-in-all-modes.screen you are binding h and t twice.  Once to focus up/down and then to next/prev.  The one later in the file will overwrite the previous.  So based on the value of your escape you should type Ctrl-T t and Ctrl-T h to move between split windows.

Comment: @Sean: Yes, I agree with you that `Ctrl-T t` and `Ctrl-T h` should be the keys. However, I get the following error continuously after typing one of them http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-stack.png

Answer (score 0):

If you start screen then type Ctrl-A ?, you'll see the help page, which lists next [n] and prev [p].  I believe that binding to next and prev instead of focus will do what you want.

Comment: I use C-T as a action key in Screen at the moment so, please, do not get confused by my help -window. I get the following help: http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-help.png